# Factorial calculation without using recursion

Tags: prolog, factorial, prolog-assert

I'm trying to implement a solution for the factorial calculation (n!) without using recursion, only using the retroaction of prolog. For example:

```
factorial(0, 1).
factorial(1, 1).
factorial(2, 2).

retroaction(X, Y) :-
factorial(K, Y),
not(K = X),
fail.

retroaction(K, Y) :- factorial(K, Y).
```

With fixed facts *factorial*, if I call the predicate *retroaction* to discover the factorial of 2, for example, I'll receive the correct answer:

```
?- retroaction(2, X).
X = 2.
```

The solution that I'm trying to implement is:

```
factorial_ret(Number, _) :-
    retractall(factorial(_, _)),
    assertz(factorial(0,1)),
    factorial(X, Y),
    not(X = Number),
    NewNumber is X + 1,
    Factorial is Y * NewNumber,
    retractall(factorial(_, _)),
    assertz(factorial(NewNumber, Factorial)),
    fail.

factorial_ret(Number, Y) :- 
    factorial(Number, Y).
```

If I try get the factorial of a number greater than 1, doesn't works. Someone have any idea of the why?

Comment: Right, @luker. Post updated.

Comment: This is a little confusing. Which predicate are you wanting to call to get the factorial? It would seem `factorial/2`, but your example uses, `retroaction/2` and your main implementation is in `factorial_ret/2` which isn't called from anywhere else.

Comment: The predicate to get the factorial is `factorial/2`. The `retroaction/2` was only an example to show the ideia of a factorial non-recursive solution.

Comment: Please clarify what you consider a "retroaction"!

Comment: When I say "retroaction" you can understand "backtracking".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @lurker pointed out, you're confusing the 'storage predicate' with the 'definition predicate'. You need the factorial/2 definition, so it makes little sense to `retractall(factorial(_,_))`.

Below, I use `retract(mem(N, F))` to retrieve the temporaries values and prepare the DB for an eventual update. There should be always only an instance of mem/2.

```
% replace recursion with a failure driven loop
:- dynamic mem/2.
factorial(X, Y) :-
    assert(mem(0, 1)),
    repeat,
    retract(mem(N, F)),
    (  X == N % done ?
    -> Y = F, % yes, succeed
       !      % but be sure to avoid 'external' backtracking...
    ;  N1 is N + 1,
       F1 is N1 * F,
       assert(mem(N1, F1)),
       fail   % loop: 'goto repeat'
    ).
```

Note that all builtins in the branch between `repeat,...,fail` are non backtrackable (well, except retract/1).

Please note also that such code will be much slower of a recursive definition (and will not work in multithreaded SWI-Prolog).

I think that assert/retract were made available early to Prolog programmers as required to handle 'knowledge bases', not to serve as global variables. Several Prologs have specialized library predicate for global variables, since there are legitimate uses of them: for instance, see [memoization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization).

PS: 'retroactive' is a term used in linear systems stability theory, I've never seen it used about programming

*edit* Could be instructive to see how the bug reported by @repeat can be solved: just swap the unification and the cut.
Well, we also need an test that X is a positive integer. Sincerely, I think this is actually *irrelevant* for the question at hand.

```
...
    (  X == N % done ?
    -> !,     % yes, be sure to avoid further backtracking
       Y = F  % unify with the computed factorial
    ;  N1 is N + 1,
...
```

Comment: I understand the solutions presented, but a detail still a little confusing for me. Before I bring this problem to the SO, I understand that the `fail/0` forces the backtracking, like I showed with the `retroaction/2` predicate in my post. But using assert and retract, that doesn't happened (in your and  @Boris solution, it was used the `repeat/0` to force that). You understand why?

Comment: fail/0 force the failure. Backtracking is a consequence of failure, *if* there are choice points left on the proof stack. But you retracted factorial/2, removing them. All other predicates are deterministic.

Comment: But I also inserted with `assertz/1` a new `factorial/2` before lance the `fail/0`. I thought that so a new choice should appear on the proof stack.

Comment: it's only one, already matched - so no choice point - I guess. To follow the details, use `?- leash(-all),trace.` and then start the program. To quit the debugger, ` ?- nodebug.`

Answer (score 2):

**無!** My conscience forces me to [un-ask your question](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mu_%28negative%29#.22Unasking.22_the_question).

For what you *seek* is a [no-no](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/no-no)—even in [imperative-programming](/questions/tagged/imperative-programming)—and more so in Prolog.

[prolog-assert](/questions/tagged/prolog-assert) surely can be very useful in some circumstances; I usually see it as a "weapon of last resort", not as the "first weapon of choice". IMO the likely consequences of using it include:

- [declarative-programming](/questions/tagged/declarative-programming) is left behind.
- [logical-purity](/questions/tagged/logical-purity) is easily lost.
- [debugging](/questions/tagged/debugging) gets a lot harder.
- [code-complexity](/questions/tagged/code-complexity) rises.
- [performance](/questions/tagged/performance) drops.
- smells like [global-variables](/questions/tagged/global-variables).

Case in point? Take the answers [by @CapelliC](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32793645/4609915) and [by @Boris](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32794599/4609915).
Quoting @Boris:

> I am writing this answer because it has a bit less unnecessary code than the *otherwise correct answer* by @CapelliC.

Let's run some queries and put that assessment to the test!

```
?- factorialBoris(0,0).
**LOOPS**

?- factorialBoris(0,2).
**LOOPS**

?- factorialBoris(1,2).
**LOOPS**

?- factorialCapelliC(0,0).
**LOOPS**

?- factorialCapelliC(0,2).
**LOOPS**
```

**нет!**

Please do not get me wrong! I do not want to put down the work and effort [by @CapelliC](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32793645/4609915) and [by @Boris](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32794599/4609915), *two [Prolog topusers on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/prolog/topusers)*,  in any way, shape or form.

---

**Bottom line:**

Using a [imperative-programming](/questions/tagged/imperative-programming) style when coding in Prolog can easily backfire!

Rigorous testing of code using [prolog-assert](/questions/tagged/prolog-assert) is much harder than testing [logically-pure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/logical-purity) code—and even *that* can be *quite a lot*, believe me!

In cases of uncertainty, choose the wise path: simply do that which is right:)

Preserve [logical-purity](/questions/tagged/logical-purity) whenever possible—don't trade it in for nothing in return.

Comment: Memoization is not a "no-no", it has valid uses. Either way, this question obviously serves the purpose of discussing a programming technique, we don't have to immediately get religious over it. And if someone actually _thinks_ that this is a good way to compute a factorial, they can as well do it.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the error in my solution, it helped me correct it.

Comment: @Boris. I did not call memoization in general a no-no. By the way, the OP didn't even mention memoization... Using memoization for something like `factorial`, however, IS a no-no, and a big one, too: your code crashed my machine today:)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that by "retroaction" you actually mean ["memoization"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization), one way to go about this would be:

> As long as you don't find the factorial you need, find the largest one so far, calculate the next, rinse and repeat.

I am writing this answer because it has a bit less unnecessary code than the otherwise correct [answer by @CapelliC](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32793645/1812457).

You need only one starting fact for this, the factorial of 0:

You then can use a `repeat` loop to do the "as long as". Then, if you always add new factorials to the top of the stack of pre-calculated factorials and you always look only once, you can be sure that you find the biggest one so far:

```
:- dynamic factorial/2.
factorial(0, 1).

factorial_memoize(N, F) :-
    repeat,
        (   factorial(N, F0)
        ->  !, F = F0
        ;   once(factorial(N0, F0)),
            succ(N0, N1),
            F1 is N1 * F0,
            asserta(factorial(N1, F1)),
            fail
        ).
```

Here is how the program works:

```
?- listing(factorial/2).
:- dynamic factorial/2.

factorial(0, 1).

true.

?- factorial_memoize(0, F).
F = 1.

?- listing(factorial/2).
:- dynamic factorial/2.

factorial(0, 1).

true.

?- factorial_memoize(5, F).
F = 120.

?- listing(factorial/2).
:- dynamic factorial/2.

factorial(5, 120).
factorial(4, 24).
factorial(3, 6).
factorial(2, 2).
factorial(1, 1).
factorial(0, 1).

true.
```

Comment: a good answer, but doesn't highlight the nastier problem that is not apparent: retract and logical updates (to be true neither mine does...)

Comment: @CapelliC I guess that goes without saying.

Comment: @CapelliC And another observation: It seems that you simply keep a "running value", while this implements proper "memoization", that it, it keeps every value it calculates along the way. Of course OP's question never said they want memoization.

Answer (score -1):

You've got a lower-case `k` in your `not` clause.

Comment: That's right, @Scott Hunter. I changed now. Remains functional.

Comment: You wrote a comment, not an answer. The program the OP presented is logically flawed, `k` or no `k`.